# Monitor Platform access and spend time of the system in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, tapestry

How can I implement following functionality in a project using or without using spring-security.

**1. LoggedIn Count:** Number of times the user has logged into the system.

**2. Time Spend:** Total time spent by user.

As of now, I have thought about the solution using javascript, in which one request will be sent to the server periodically. And inside the server it will increment the spendtime variable.

Still would like to know that, is there anything coming alongwith spring-security itself or not. Or any other idea to handle such functionality.

Any idea/suggestion would be highly appreciated...

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very clear question - can you maybe rephrase in a way that is clearer as to - from a functional perspective - what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Peter Mularien Updated the question... Let me know if you still find any queries within it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For the numer of logins the best way is to plug in to Spring Security using AuthenticationSuccessHandler, as `@user395072` said and hold the result in user table in `numOfSuccessfulLogins` adding +1 on every successful login.

2) For the time spent on the site all You need is a session variable, lets'a call it `$MY_TIME`. Then **on every request** if `$MY_TIME` doesn't exist in session, you set it to the current date (i.e. `System.currentTimeMillis()`). If it does exist, than You take the current time and substract the `$MY_TIME` value and You have the time spent so far in current session. On the same request You need need to persist it. You can have a separete table for it adding a new record when You set the `$MY_TIME` to session and updating the newest one every other time. Or You can have 2 fields in user table: `cumulativeTime` and `currentSessionTime`, and You add update `cumulativeTime += currentSessionTime` and `currentSessionTime = 0` when settin `$MY_TIME` to session, and on any other request update `currentSessionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - $MY_TIME`.

Answer (score 2):

I worked with those exactly same technologies in the past(just not SpringSecurity) and i did a similar thing, i think i can give you an idea of how you could do that. I think it will work:

**1**
To count the name of successful logins, you will need a variable in an entity.
That variable needs to increase by one when the user successfully logs. I think the best time to increase that value is if the validation is correct and the access is granted(You could implement that in the validation method). 
So what you do is get the current value of the variable for that user using the Hibernate Query Language, add 1 and then update the row.

**2**
For this one i am not sure at 100% but you can give it a try:
A variable in the User table called **loginTime** needs to exist as @ApplicationState.

Then in your logout function you will create a tempVariable that will hold the time(a long variable) at that current time.
You will do a substract operation(logOutTime - logInTime) and you will get the time in milliseconds expend on that session. 
So just before erasing the session and loging out for real, just update a column in the DB for the user that is going to logout with the result.

Also i would like to mention that this 2 ideas might solve the problem using a programmatical approach, but i am sure that if you investigate about Spring Security, you might find the way of finding that info in some kind of logs or similar(Never used Spring Security before)

I hope i explained my self correctly.
Good Luck

Comment: @sfrj... nice to have an explained answer which satisfied me somewhat... Still for point no. 2, I have few concerns like (1) what if user have spend an hour, and browser gets crashed or (2) what if user doesn't logout from the system properly ? –

Comment: @Nirmal Regarding to (1) Well in that case, we would need to have that algorithm implemented not just in the log-out function maybe somewhere else perhaps a servlet or some bean at the application context level, that can detect that the session for that user is not active any more.  Regarding to (2) Same as (1) also i think that in the case that this scenarios occur, the chance of not getting an exact session time is high. Im sure there has to be an easy way for that, you will need to investigate deeper(Read carefully about Spring Security features maybe that helps).

Comment: For the time spent You should calculate it **on every request**, not on logout. No special session ending detection is needed. I define the user session length as the time from the first request creating the session till the last request in the same session. To count that You can use a common `javax.servlet.Filter`, or better a `HandlerInterceptor` if You're using Spring MVC - nothing to do with Spring Security. See my answer for details.

Comment: OK, you _could_ add a custom filter to [Spring Security Filter Chain](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) if you'd really want, but simpler methods exist, as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this, it depends on the architecture that you are following.

you can use following

```
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent(authResult, this.getClass()));
        }
    }
```

or

of using spring security

```
 <bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
     p:sessionAuthenticationStrategy-ref="sas"
     p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager"
    p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

or using any custom filters

Few more pointers which people generally use for user tracking/analysis

1. capturing the user agent with user information
2. capturing the login and logout / session expiry time
3. capturing the IP address
4. capturing the unsuccessful login attempts
5. capturing the session identifier with login

Once all this information is stored in a persistent store, they usually create a report / procedure on top of it to get all those information like how many users in a single day, or how many times a user have logged-in during a month or how long did he spent on the site during a month etc...